# Drush not working properly on Ubuntu

Tags: drush

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 . When I try to download, enable, disable any module drush gives the following error:

## Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

### Original

Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container. in Drupal::getContainer() (line 129 of /var/www/html/gitrepo/drupal/core/lib/Drupal.php).

```
Drupal::getContainer()
drupal8_bootstrap(0)
_drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration()
drush_bootstrap(3, 7)
drush_bootstrap_max()
drush_bootstrap_to_phase(-2)
Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
drush_main()
```

### Additional

Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container. in Drupal::getContainer() (line 129 of /var/www/html/gitrepo/drupal/core/lib/Drupal.php).

```
Drupal::getContainer()
Drupal::theme()
_drupal_log_error(Array, 1)
_drupal_exception_handler(Object)
```

---

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                             [error]

Comment: Trying to get more info: Are you accessing drush from the root folder? Does Drush respond to other commands such as `drush --version`? Can you post the command that produces that output (and give the folder location).

Comment: Any command from anywhere is the drupal folder gives the same result.

Comment: At this point I'm placing bets on @greg_1_anderson response. D8 moves fast. APIs change. The drush version may be off. I'm going to advise on using a Dev VM that has Drupal 8 installed along with proper dependencies. That *greatly* reduces the headache of D8 development -- at least right now. Best of luck.

Comment: Just another potential helpful article: Install Drush 7 for Drupal 8 without throwing away Drush 6 http://x-team.com/2015/02/install-drush-drupal-8

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are not using the right version of Drush.  For Drupal 8.0-beta7, you need Drush 7.0.0-alpha9.  For Drupal 8.0-beta6, you need Drush 7.0.0-alpha8.

Drupal 8 APIs are changing rapidly; if you have mixed versions, you can easily encounter spurious problems.  Tracking HEAD of Drupal 8.0.x and Drush master is another viable strategy.

Comment: yes, D8 development has made me upgrade drush several times while facing error messages like these. I'm just doing it old school for now not to get too frustrated :)

Comment: I am having drush version 7.0-dev. Is it right version. If not how can I find which version is suitable for my drupal installation?

Comment: Drush 7.0-dev is not a version, it is a branch.  If you install like darol100 suggests, Drush should work on the day you install it, but you might occasionally need to run `git pull` from the Drush directory to update to the latest head.  To install a specific version of Drush, install via Composer as described in the Drush installation documentation: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Thanks this worked I installed an alpha release for drush and its now working.

Answer (score 1):

For D8 don't you [need php 5.4+](https://www.drupal.org/requirements)? Check your version of PHP. I believe Ubuntu 14.x has 5.3 by default but that's just a wild guess.

What do you see when you execute `php --version` on the commandline?

You may need to upgrade through a [back channel upgrade through other PPAs](http://www.ubtutorials.com/tutorial/1085/setup-php-54-ubuntu-1404) or run Drupal in a Virtual Machine / [Vagrant](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-dev-vm).

Comment: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10)

Comment: Well that qualifies!  IF this is just a dev project, you may still want to investigate the vagrant route. This repo is pretty much a fully configured machine to run D6, 7, or 8. https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-dev-vm

Comment: But on the same thing is working with another local installation of drupal on same machine... What can be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the wrong version or you installed wrong.

Here are the instruction on how to install Drush on Ubuntu.

```
# Install Composer
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

# Access composer from anywhere on your system:
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install Drush
cd /usr/share
sudo git clone --branch master https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
cd drush
composer install
cd ~/
# Access drush from anywhere on your system:
ln -s /usr/share/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
```

Source: [lazydubuntu/bin/basictools.sh](https://github.com/darol100/lazydubuntu/blob/master/bin/basictools.sh)

This would make sure that you installed the latest version